# Finding parents and precise Date of Birth for child born in Massachusetts in 1919?

Tags: united-states, birth-records, 1910s, massachusetts

The only record I can find for a child born in Massachusetts in 1919 has the name and year of birth, but not much else.

This is a [link](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/3928/41263_2421406273_0299-00550?pid=1877609&backurl=https://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?indiv%3D1%26dbid%3D3928%26h%3D1877609%26tid%3D%26pid%3D%26usePUB%3Dtrue%26_phsrc%3DmOm158%26_phstart%3DsuccessSource&treeid=&personid=&hintid=&usePUB=true&_phsrc=mOm158&_phstart=successSource&usePUBJs=true) from Ancestry.com's *Massachusetts, Birth Index, 1860-1970* for Julia Sciascio.  You will need a subscription to view it.

[image]

How can I determine her parents' names and her precise date of birth (DOB)?

Comment: That is an index to the full entries and, like most indexes, doesn't contain the detail that we all want. Following through links from Ancestry's notes on the index, it seems like the originals are at Massachusetts Archives. Their site talks only in terms of using the indexes to access the originals at the Archives. Maybe a Massachusetts expert can comment on ways to access the originals?

Comment: How to insert pictures is described at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information in the index makes it straightforward to find the original birth record, if you know of what it is an index. In this case, it is quite self-explanatory, this is an index of centrally-archived births in the state of Massachusetts between 1916 and 1920.

You know that the birth was in the town of Worcester, archived in volume 178, page 92, of the statewide Massachusetts birth returns.

FamilySearch holds many historic vital records for the United States, and many are digitised and indexed. Searching the FamilySearch Catalog brings up:

[**Massachusetts, statewide birth records, 1916-1920**](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/1950815?availability=Family%20History%20Library)

Scrolling down to volume 178, and paging through to page 92 finds the [original birth record](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:33SQ-G17L-PH8?i=92&cc=1928860&cat=1950815), which reveals:

- date of birth: 17 Jan 1919
- father: John Sciascio
- mother: Grace Monapoli
- and much more...

Comment: Advice over the wider date-range can be found in the FamilySearch Wiki on https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Massachusetts_Genealogy_Guide#Vital_Records 
The FS Catalogue and FS Wiki are 2 must-have things to have in your favourites / book marks....  I haven't read it through yet myself so can't vouch for the contents.